# Prove that $512^3 + 675^3 + 720^3$ is a composite number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We have to prove that the number

$$N=512^3 + 675^3 + 720^3$$

is **composite.**

> I tried to use the identity $(a^3+b^3+c^3)=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)+3abc$ hoping to take out some common factors from the **R.H.S.** but it didn't work. I also used $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ (in all possible combos) and tried to combine with $c^3$ but that too didn't work. I nearly spent about 5 hours struggling with the question but no result :(
>   Please help!
>   Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://cms.math.ca/Concours/MOCP/98-99/ps-4.html

Comment: Should be posted as the answer.

Comment: Even sweeter : http://www.sciencechatforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=5975

Comment: Kudos to the previous commenters for not going to the smart-aleck answer. You left the door open to it by neglecting to mention the stricture that you can't use a calculator or computer to factorize it. In the mathlete context, one would waste too much time looking for the least prime factor, which in this case is the 50th prime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well there may be so many ways to answer. One of my teachers in a math-camp gave the following way out. I think its a good one.

Let $a=512, b=675, c=720$. Now the number looks like $a^3+b^3+c^3$ but we require a sort of $3abc$ term to resolve it into factors. First we factorize $a,b,c$ into prime factors. So, $a=2^9, b=3^3\times 5^2, c=2^4\times 3^2\times 5$. Now it can be seen that $2c^2=3ab$. Hence, $a^3+b^3+c^3=a^3+b^3-c^3+2c^2c$ and thus the problem can be solved. It can then be seen that the given number is composite.

I have posted the same question in Q & A style [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833714/is-512367537203-a-composite-number/833715#833715). I did not see your question earlier. One of the users gave the link to your question in a comment on my question.